# How do I post on Google Blogger on behalf on another author?

Tags: blogs, blogger, blogspot

Is there any way that the author can give permission to post on behalf of his/her account? Or any other way to set author in Google Blogger posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cant post on behalf of another author unless you have his Blogger login credential. But you can definitely post by being an author of that Blog.

The admin of that blog must add you as an author before you can start posting. Tell the admin to follow this -

Go to Blogger dashboard>Settings>Basic. Now head over to the Permissions section

[image: Blogger add author]

Click **+ Add authors** button and type the email address of the new author.

[image: Type blogger author email address]

An invitation email will be sent to the newly invited author. Now the author has to accept the invitation, That's it.